# Die if a values in an array are higher than 16 or less than 4

Tags: php, arrays

So I want this code to check if all the values in an array are less than 16 or higher than 4.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$details = array($username, $password);

foreach($details as $detail){
    $len = strlen($detail);
    if($len>16 || $len<4) {
    die('Too short');
    }
}
```

So this is what I have so far, however when I enter a value less than 4 or greater than 16 it doesn't say anything, so obviously it doesn't work.
When I did `echo $len;` it did echo the right values tho.

Comment: Why can't I enter a password longer than 16 characters? I'll have you know my password is "super long password that nobody will ever guess" :p

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know, just for the sake of practice, I guess.

Comment: Add `var_dump($detail);` inside the foreach -- what's the output?

Comment: string(6) "qwerty" string(9) "fasdfasdf"

Comment: @Kris: And now -- why do you think that should trigger the `die()` statement?

Comment: Well, later I'm going to put it into a database, so I do die to kill the page and the data wont be put into the database if it's grater than 16 or less than 4..

Comment: @Kris There's nothing wrong with your handler. Check your form and see if you have something to the affect of (named inputs) `<input type="text" name="username">` and `<input type="text" name="password">`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your handler, I tested it with a quick form I put together and it worked 100%

Check to see if your form has something to the affect of (named inputs) such as:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="password">
```